Android phone stuck in bootloader mode reboot after `fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img`
Android phone  stuck in bootloader mode reboot after fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img commands execution:
phone band: google pixel 4xl  
OS: factory image android 12.  
root: got.  
bootloader state: unlocked.

How can I resolve it before successful boot up? more thanks.

I found solution , check your kernel's cmdline parameter value, it may be that  kernel is not right stock edition.

I found me chose a wrong kernel source for my pixel 4xl phone, after  changed kernel  source as google's stock kernel source , I successfully  built kernel and disabled verity successfully.
